# ASP.net WebForms Extensionless URLs

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, url-routing

I understand that in ASP.net 4.0 URL Routing has been incorporated into Web Forms. It is great that I can do something like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Category", "list/{id}/{name}", "~/category.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Product", "item/{id}/{name}", "~/product.aspx");
}
```

But is there a built-in way for me to route extension-less urls to their .aspx counterparts without manually adding a route for every file? For example:

```
account/login => account/login.aspx
contact-us => contact-us.aspx
```

Thanks

---

I've added the following as a catch-all rule at the end of my routes and it seems to be working.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "{*file}", "~/{file}.aspx");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use placeholders like in MVC

**VB.NET**

```
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "ThreeLevels",
        "{folder}/{file}/{id}",
        "~/{folder}/{file}.aspx", True,
        New RouteValueDictionary From {
            {"folder", "Home"},
            {"file", "Default"},
            {"id", Nothing}
        })
```

**C#**

```
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "ThreeLevels",
        "{folder}/{file}/{id}",
        "~/{folder}/{file}.aspx", true,
        new RouteValueDictionary {
            {"folder", "Home"},
            {"file", "Default"},
            {"id", null}
        });
```